# PHP If minimum value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop in PHP and I need to find the lowest number in a column of a table.

I have tried this:

```
$sql="SELECT * from pages order by menu_order ASC ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
echo '<a href="edit_page.php?pagename='.$result["pagename"].'">'.$result["title"].'</a>';
if($result["sequence"] == min)
{
//do something here
}
else
{
//do something else
}
}
```

but that didn't work - any ideas?

Comment: try `$sql="SELECT * from pages order by menu_order ASC  LIMIT BY (0,1)";` to fetch the minimum value only

Comment: sorry - i may not have been too clear - i need to fetch all rows but within the loop i need to say the row with the minimum value does something different - displays something else

Comment: If efficiency is not a concern, just do two queries; one to grab the minimum value.

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated; it is strongly recommended to switch away from them and use the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the min, try this one following,

```
$sql   = "SELECT * from pages order by menu_order ASC LIMIT BY (0,1)";
$r     = mysql_query($sql); // I don't like mysql_*
$d     = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$min   = $d['sequence'];
```

Now we know the `min` value. Let's implement it :)

```
$sql="SELECT * from pages order by menu_order ASC ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo '<a href="edit_page.php?pagename='.$result["pagename"].'">'.$result["title"].'</a>';

    if($result["sequence"] == $min)   // Note that it's $min
    {
    //do something here
    }
    else
    {
    //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY menu_order ASC LIMIT 1";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL to query the minimum value without needing to any extra PHP code.

```
$sql="SELECT MIN(sequence) FROM pages";
```

Run that query and you'll get the minimum value from the `sequence` field.